# Android Custom Toast Message not working in a separate class

Tags: java, android, toast, android-toast

I have created the following method for custom toast.

```
public void customToastMessage(String message){
    LayoutInflater inf = (LayoutInflater)con.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View layout = inf.inflate(R.layout.custom_toast_layout,(ViewGroup)findViewById(R.id.myCustomToast));
    TextView toastMessage = layout.findViewById(R.id.myCustomToastText);
    toastMessage.setText(message);
    Toast warningMessage = Toast.makeText(con, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    warningMessage.setGravity(Gravity.TOP | Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL, 0, 10);
    warningMessage.setView(layout);
    warningMessage.show();
}
```

As long as this method exists in MainActivity, it works fine but when I move it to a separate class I get:

> "java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:389)".

What do I need to change in my class below?

```
public class MyCustomUI extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static Context con;

    public MyCustomUI(Context con){
        this.con = con;
    }

    public void customToastMessage(String message){
         LayoutInflater inf = (LayoutInflater)con.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
         View layout = inf.inflate(R.layout.custom_toast_layout,(ViewGroup)findViewById(R.id.myCustomToast));
         TextView toastMessage = layout.findViewById(R.id.myCustomToastText);
         toastMessage.setText(message);
         Toast warningMessage = Toast.makeText(con, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
         warningMessage.setGravity(Gravity.TOP | Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL, 0, 10);
         warningMessage.setView(layout);
         warningMessage.show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing your problem is when you inflate your layout:

> View layout = inf.inflate(R.layout.custom_toast_layout,(ViewGroup)findViewById(R.id.myCustomToast));

I'm also guessing the problem is `(ViewGroup)findViewById(R.id.myCustomToast)`. You are trying to look for a View/ViewGroup that does not exist on that class but on your MainActivity.

Pass it as an argument to your method (just the relevant part):

```
public void customToastMessage(String message, ViewGroup customToast){
    LayoutInflater inf = (LayoutInflater)con.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View layout = inf.inflate(R.layout.custom_toast_layout, viewgroup);
```

Comment: in MainActivity when calling the method, what do i pass as a parameter for ViewGroup customToast?

Comment: (ViewGroup)findViewById(R.id.myCustomToast)